# Control light intensity with a UI slider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on 2D game in Unity and I' m wondering how we can manage brightness with a slider which is in the option menu of my game. I wanted to know what are the steps to solve this problem.

Comment: Hello Yacine - So Brightness with a slider - I'm assuming through lights than instead of overall.  I just done a quick search - using c# - this may start you off without knowing anymore. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDvPNNgIu7k  If you have done anything code wise please send it up here and someone may be able to give you more guidance.

Comment: This may be worth a wee look too - https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-there-a-standard-way-of-implementing-a-brightness-gamma-slider-in-unity.343527/

Comment: By 'brightness', do you mean light intensity?

Comment: Bolkay, yes I mean light intensity.

Comment: I've already watched the video you send me but the onGUI method is supposed to create a new slider. In my situation, I would like to manage brightness with slider which is my option menu, I don't want to create any other slider but just use the slider I have in my option menu.

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to the slider's `onValueChanged` event to be notified when the slider value changes. When that happens, assign the slider's value to the light's intensity value: `Light.intensity = Slider.value`.

That's it.

```
//Add your slider from the Editor
public Slider sliderRef;
//Add your light from the Editor
public Light lightRef;

void OnEnable()
{
    //Subscribe to the Slider Click event
    sliderRef.onValueChanged.AddListener(sliderCallBack);
}

//Will be called when Slider changes
void sliderCallBack(float value)
{
    Debug.Log("Slider Value Changed: " + value);
    lightRef.intensity = sliderRef.value;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Subscribe To Slider Event
    sliderRef.onValueChanged.RemoveAllListeners();
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're not using anything that requires the `OnGUI` function. You can find a tutorial for the new UI system in Unity that also covers sliders [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/user-interface-ui)

Comment: Thanks for answering, i've written your code, but then I don't know to which component I have to attach my script because when I want to apply the methods to my slider, I can't find them in the on value changed.

Comment: I don't get you. With the script from my answer, drag the GameObject that has the slider component to the sliderRef slot. Drag the GameObject that has the Light component to the lightRef slot. That's all you have to do....

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are a few options depending what you are hoping to achieve; but these come to mind:

1. Use a semi-transparent black quad in front of the camera and simply change the material colour, this is probably the easiest. Cons, will slow performance due to alpha on whole screen
2. Use a post process effect https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessingOverview.html. Cons, will slow performance
3. If you are using custom shaders then you could have a global variable that defines brightness https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.SetGlobalFloat.html
4. Find a way to manipulate the native brightness for the phone, this would be a bit trickier and might not be the effect you desire

Comment: Thanks for answering,I know that we can use the post processing but how we can use it to make effect to manage brightness with a slider.